# Unable to access child functions using ref in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, router

I am able to access functions of child component using ref without the router

Below code works

```
//handleTimer is function called inside the child component 

handleTimer() {
   this.refs.tasks.clearTimer()
}
render() {
return (
  <TaskList ref="tasks" title="First Task" setTimer={this. handleTimer.bind(this)}/>

)}
```

But when i add routing functionality, it throws error 
"**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.tasks.clearTimer')**
"

Here is the code which doesn't work, when handleTimer is called

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
            <Route exact path="/tasks" render={()=> <TaskList ref="tasks" title="First Task" setTimer={this. handleTimer.bind(this)}/>}  />

            </div>
         </BrowserRouter>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using react-router v3.2

Comment: string refs are deprecated. Try to use function type of ref https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thank you :)

I changed it to ref={tasks=> {this.tasks = tasks}}
and replaced this.refs.tasks with this.tasks
and its working as expected